# Outlook Recurring Appointment Change Does Not Release Meeting Room Resource

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Microsoft Outlook 2007

I create a recurring appointment. Say every week on Tuesday at 2:00PM. I book a meeting room as a resource.

The next Monday I decide I want to change the weekly occurrence of the appointment, so I move it to Wednesday at 2:00PM.

This should free up the meeting room so that I can schedule a different appointment there for Tuesday at 2:00PM, but it doesn't. The meeting room stays booked and Outlook will not allow me or anybody else to schedule a new appointment there.

Why doesn't Outlook free up the resource?

Answer (score 0):

Because Outlook only notifies the rooms the meeting is currently in.  Because the original room is still taken by you, you can have your other meeting in it; meeting participants will not know that the room has declined your (second) meeting invitation.

(I'm seeing the same behavior even with Office365.  I'd love having a better answer for you.)